# How to get current URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, converters

I have a current URL:

```
http://www.test.com/p1234?utm_source=....
```

How do I get a URL with the format `http://www.test.php/p1234`

I am using javascript `document.URL`, the  result is `http://www.test.com/p1234?utm_source=....`

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct answer:

```
window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: also prefix the protocol used.
window.location.protocal + "//" window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
var location = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
```

see the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location